# Slice pandas timeseries relative to condition

Tags: pandas, datetime, slice

I need to slice a pandas timeseries 60 minutes before a condition occurs, for example 60 seconds before the number in column 'Signal' == 1

Now, Im using .tail(60) on the entire dataframe up until the desired index, but this is very inefficient

```
def create_sequences(signal, label,  data):
    """Function to return seqs of 60 secs prior to condition"""
    sequences = []

    for i in signal:
        sequence = data.loc[:i].tail(60)
        if len(sequence) == 60:
            sequences.append((np.array(sequence.drop('Signal', 
                                       axis=1)).transpose(), label))


    return sequences


# To generate some data for reproduction
periods = 7 * 24 * 60
tidx = pd.date_range('2019-09-01', periods=periods, freq='T')
ts = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=tidx)
ts['Signal'] = ts[0].apply(lambda x: 1 if x > 0 else 0)

ones = ts[ts.Signal == 1].index.values


x = create_sequences(ones, 1, ts)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've slightly modified the data generation script,

```
periods = 7 * 24 * 60
tidx = pandas.date_range('2019-09-01', periods=periods, freq='T')
ts = pandas.DataFrame(index=tidx)
ts['Signal'] = 0
```

And introduced a '1' in the row 1000 (over 10080 rows),

```
ts['Signal'].iloc[1000] = 1
```

Firstly just quickly check that the timestamp index is sorted,

```
 In[1]: ts.index.is_monotonic_increasing
Out[1]: True
```

Import `tqdm` to measure performance

```
from tqdm import tqdm
```

Two options, since the resolution of the time series is 1 minute, the result will be the same here, but you may use one or the other depending on the result you expect.

1.If you want your resulting slices to be overlapping like a sliding window you may use `.iterrows()`

```
D = pandas.Timedelta('00:00:60')
sequences = []

for timestamp, row in tqdm(ts.iterrows()):
    if ts.loc[timestamp:timestamp + D, 'Signal'].sum() > 0: 
        break
    sequences.append(ts.loc[timestamp:timestamp + D])
```

2.If you want your resulting slices to be sequential and not overlap,

```
D = pandas.Timedelta('00:00:60')
sequences = []

nmax = numpy.trunc((ts.index.max() - ts.index.min()) / D)

for n in range(0, int(nmax)):
  if ts.loc[ts.index.min() + (n * D):ts.index.min()  + (1 + n) * D, 'Signal'].sum() > 0: 
    break
  sequences.append(ts.loc[ts.index.min() + (n * D):ts.index.min()  + (1 + n) * D])
```

Both executions were inferior to one second, but if you are seeking for faster performance, you may check `.itertuples()` (ref. https://medium.com/@formigone/stop-using-df-iterrows-2fbc2931b60e)

Comment: @Rob did you have a chance to review the answer?

Comment: Hi, Sorry about the late answer. I decided to approach this a little different, but used alot from your answer nr. 1

Comment: No worries, happy to know it was a bit helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This is working, A bit slow for big datasets though

```
sequences = []
for timestamp, row in ts.iterrows():

    data = ts.loc[timestamp:timestamp + pd.Timedelta(seconds=60),:]
    label = ts.Signal.loc[timestamp + pd.Timedelta(seconds=60)]
    sequences.append((ts.drop('Signal', axis=1).values, label))
```